# OnBackButtonPressed not being fired in Xamarin android (hardware back button not working)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, onbackpressed

I recently started working on an Xamarin android project with an already established structure (in other words, someone else started it) and I'm having problems with the hardware back button. In a specific page, it just doesn't work. Like, at all. Not even a breakpoint will hit the `OnBackButtonPressed` override. This is said view:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MessagesView : ContentPage
{
    public ListView ListView { get { return listView; } }
    private bool IsChatEmpty { get { return listView.ItemsSource.Cast<Message>().Count() == 0; } }

    public MessagesView(MessageRoom messageRoom)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, true); // I added this line in the hopes it would fix the problem, but it does nothing in my case
        BindingContext = new MessagesViewModel(messageRoom);
        ScrollToEnd(false);
    }

    private void btnSend_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var viewModel = (MessagesViewModel)BindingContext;
        if (viewModel.LastMessage == string.Empty)
            return;

        viewModel.SendMessage();
        RefreshMessageList();
    }

    public void ScrollToEnd(bool animated)
    {
        if (listView.ItemsSource == null || IsChatEmpty)
            return;

        var target = listView.ItemsSource.Cast<Message>().Last();
        listView.ScrollTo(target, ScrollToPosition.End, animated);
    }

    public void RefreshMessageList()
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            listView.ItemsSource = null;
            listView.ItemsSource = ((MessagesViewModel)BindingContext).MessageRoom.Messages;
            ScrollToEnd(true);
        });
    }

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
    }
}
```

Most of this code is not useful for the matter at issue, but I went ahead and posted all of it just in case. There is something else I'd like to add regarding how the code is wired-up: this page is now a navigation page, but it started as a modal and it used to work fine. I'm only one month into Xamarin, so I don't know every nook and cranny of it, but the guy who laid out this project only used modals, this is the first navpage in the whole thing. When I was trying to open the navpage with `await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(page)`, it just wouldn't work. Then I found out about `MasterDetailPage`, and that's what he used. This method is used to open every page in the application:

```
public void SetDetailMasterPage(Type poType, params object[] poArgs)
{
    MasterDetailPage oPage = (MasterDetailPage)App.Current.MainPage;
    oPage.IsPresented = false;

    if (poArgs.Length > 0)
        oPage.Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(poType, poArgs));
    else
        oPage.Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(poType));
}
```

So I finally came around and changed how I did my PushAsync:

```
public async Task OpenPage(Page page)
{
    await ((MasterDetailPage)App.Current.MainPage).Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(page);
}
```

And that works. Bottomline, the back button in a navigation page isn't working when such page is called from a modal in a master detail page. Or at least, that's what I gathered from all of this.

I don't want a menu in this specific navigation page and it's only a *navigation page* because they want a frikkin' back button in the navigation bar, but as it stands, hardware back button is stuck in this page.

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Check your android project main activity.cs .I also faced to this issue because I put empty back button clicked event in main activity. After removed it from my code back button event worked fine